# Install new theme for Magento. Fatal error: Class 'ThemeAdminPanel_ExtraConfig_Helper_Data' not found in .../app/Mage.php on line 546

Tags: php, magento

I install new theme for magento and change "System > Configuration"> Design.
I write name for new theme in themes options. After "Save config" now I get error when try go to "System > Configuration": Class 'ThemeAdminPanel_ExtraConfig_Helper_Data' not found in .../app/Mage.php on line 546

When upload files for new theme I see that create new folders in `app/code/local`:

```
/app/code/local/ThemeAdminPanel
/app/code/local/Mage
```

app/code/local/ThemeAdminPanel/ExtraConfig/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <ThemeAdminPanel_ExtraConfig>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <depends>
            <!-- no dependencies -->
            </depends>
        </ThemeAdminPanel_ExtraConfig>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <!-- ... -->
            <ExtraConfig>
                <class>ThemeAdminPanel_ExtraConfig_Model</class>
            </ExtraConfig>   
            <!-- ... -->
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <ExtraConfig>
                <class>ThemeAdminPanel_ExtraConfig_Helper</class>
            </ExtraConfig>
        </helpers>
        <resources />
        <extraconfig />
        <blocks>
            <mygeneral><class>ThemeAdminPanel_ExtraConfig_Block</class></mygeneral>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <!---->
    <default>
        <mygeneral>
            <generaloptions>
                <menutype>1</menutype>
                <topbanner>default/phone.png</topbanner>
                <googlefont>Source Sans Pro:200,200italic,300,300italic,regular,italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,900,900italic</googlefont>
                <additional_nav>Contacts</additional_nav>
                <additional_nav_href>index.php/contacts/</additional_nav_href>
                <topbtn>1</topbtn>
                <enable_ajax>1</enable_ajax>
        <hide_wish>0</hide_wish>
        <hide_compare>0</hide_compare>
        <hide_cart>0</hide_cart>


            </generaloptions>
            <background>
                <maincolor>F7F7F9</maincolor>
                <pattern>default/pattern.png</pattern>
                <bg_repeat></bg_repeat>
                <bg_attachment></bg_attachment>
                <bg_position_x></bg_position_x>
                <bg_position_y></bg_position_y>
            </background>            
            <product_list>

                <shorten_name>23</shorten_name>

                <layer>1</layer>
                <sale_label>1</sale_label>
                <sale_label_text>Sale</sale_label_text>
                <new_label>1</new_label>
                <new_label_text>New</new_label_text>
            </product_list>
            <share>
                    <facebookgroupid>115403961948855</facebookgroupid>
                <twittername>dedalx</twittername>
                <use_share>1</use_share>
                <share_code><![CDATA[<span class='st_fblike_hcount' displayText='Facebook Like'></span>
<span class='st_twitter_hcount' displayText='Tweet'></span>
<span class='st_pinterest_hcount' displayText='Pinterest'></span>
<span class='st_plusone_hcount' displayText='Google +1'></span>]]></share_code>
            </share>
            <slideshow>
                <use_slideshow>1</use_slideshow>
                <hide_right_sliders>0</hide_right_sliders>
                <autoplay>1</autoplay>
                <speed>8000</speed>
                <slides_count>2</slides_count>
            </slideshow>
            <productpage>

                <use_zoom>1</use_zoom>
                <use_carousel>1</use_carousel>
            </productpage>
            <colors>
                <active_color>6CBE42</active_color>
                <button_hover>58BAE9</button_hover>
            </colors>
        <customcode>
                <customcss>/* Add any CSS code here */</customcss>
                <customjs>// Add any JavaScript code here</customjs>
            </customcode>
        </mygeneral>
    </default>
    <!---->
    <adminhtml>
    <menu>
            <metroshop translate="title" module="ExtraConfig">
                <title>MetroShop</title>
                <sort_order>6666</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <settings translate="title" module="ExtraConfig">
                                <title>Theme Settings</title>
                                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                                <action>adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/mygeneral</action>
                            </settings>
                </children>

            </metroshop>
        </menu>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <ExtraConfig>
                    <file>options.xml</file>
                </ExtraConfig>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>     
</config>
```

app/code/local/ThemeAdminPanel/ExtraConfig/Helper/Data.php:

```
<?php 
class ThemeAdminPanel_ExtraConfig_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
?>
```

I see that this class added to code but can't find in /app/Mage.php in this part:

```
public static function helper($name)
    {
        $registryKey = '_helper/' . $name;
        if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
            $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);
            self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);
        }
        return self::registry($registryKey);
    }
```

As I understand have some problem in theme about adding class to Mage.php.

Additional in file etc/config.xml don't have Class 'ThemeAdminPanel_ExtraConfig_Helper_Data'. But' I'm not sure how to fix and solve this problem.

Please, help me to solve this problem.

All cache clean by FTP.

Comment: I don't think that this will help because can't find class `ThemeAdminPanel`, not `ThemeAdmin`

Comment: 1) Clear cache ( System > Cache management )
2. If you are using compilation, disable it or run recompile ( System > Tools > Compilation )

Comment: all cache delete by ftp